# When Combining data from multiple workbooks into a master with VBA, how do I omit specific files?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder with a master tracker and multiple workbooks. The code below compiles the workbook data into the master, as expected.

However, I'd like to have one or two wb's in that folder that this code excludes/does not open without having to include the title of every wb in the code (so I can add additional wb's as needed without having to update the script).

I've tried adding a skip like below but I can't seem to get it in the right spot in my code since the file paths and names for the data I want are purposefully designed to not require titles.

```
FName As String

If FName = "Workbook(s) I want omitted" Then GoTo Skip

Skip:
    'Find the next file
    FName = Dir
  Loop
  'Done

         Sub MASTERPULL()
    Dim wb As String, i As Long, sh As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheet = ActiveSheet
        '<----omitted some formatting code
    wb = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\*")
    Do Until wb = ""
        If wb <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
            Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & wb
                For Each sh In Workbooks(wb).Worksheets
                        sh.UsedRange.Offset(1).Copy    '<---- Assumes 1 header row
                            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sh.Name).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                        Application.CutCopyMode = False
                Next sh
            Workbooks(wb).Close False
        End If
        wb = Dir
         Call sourceSheet.Activate
         Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
        End Sub
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `Rows.Count` as you are using it is not being fully qualified, so it will be looking at the `Rows.Count` of the active sheet, not necessarily the one you are specifying.

Comment: Is there a way to make it so the workbook(s) I want omitted/not pulled into the master never become active?

Comment: `If wb <> ThisWorkbook.Name And wb <> "Workbook you want omitted" And wb <> "Workbook2 you want omitted" Then`

Comment: @BigBen I'm assuming you meant, "Then no"? But I want to make sure I understand. So, if I want to omit one workbook from the folder, I  have to identify each workbook in the code? I can't only identify the one I want omitted? Thank you!

Comment: The `<>` means not equal - so you're omitting just those one or two workbooks, which will not get opened.

Comment: @BigBen while your recommendation will work 100%, she's looking for a solution that does _not_ require her to edit code every time she changes the list of files to be skipped, which is an admirable goal.

Comment: @FreeMan I took it that OP thought a comprehensive list of all the files in the folder, except for the ones to be skipped, was needed, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: @BigBen that may be the case today, but paragraph 2 explicitly states she doesn't want to have to edit code when the list changes.

Comment: Both these options were really helpful. BigBen was correct in identifying my thought process but your "outside the box" solution @freeman was what I didn't know I needed. Thank you both so much!

Comment: @BigBen So, I had a chance to test this out but it's still opening the And wb <> "Workbook you want omitted"

Comment: If wb <> ThisWorkbook.Name And wb <> "Workbook you want omitted" Then '(This is supposed to exclude the open workbook and the “omitted” wb from opening but it still opens the “Workbook you want omitted and then throws an error on this line: ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sh.Name).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
.  I think it wants me to qualify the wb.open and ranges but I wanted them to be generic so I can reuse this as a template.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out! I needed the .xlsm in the title name. ah, so silly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `ThisWorkbook` is the one where the code resides, add a worksheet (potentially hidden if other people will look at the workbook and you don't want them to mess with the list) that contains the list of files to skip. Reference that worksheet to populate the list of files not to open.

Note that this is some "air code" - it compiles but isn't guaranteed to be 100% perfect.

- I created a new worksheet and renamed it (via the Project Explorer `Right-Click | Rename`) to `SkipList`.
- I also added a reference to the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` (`Tools | References` scroll down 'til you find that text).

```
Option Explicit

Sub MASTERPULL()
  Dim wb As String, i As Long, sh As Worksheet

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

  Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
  Set sourceSheet = ActiveSheet
        '<----omitted some formatting code

  '----------------Change here ----------------------------
  Dim skipList As Scripting.Dictionary
  Set skipList = GetFilesToIgnore

  wb = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\*")
  Do Until wb = ""
    '----------------Change here ----------------------------
    If Not skipList.Exists(wb) Then
      Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & wb
      For Each sh In Workbooks(wb).Worksheets
        sh.UsedRange.Offset(1).Copy              '<---- Assumes 1 header row
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sh.Name).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
      Next sh
      Workbooks(wb).Close False
    End If
    wb = Dir
    Call sourceSheet.Activate
  Loop

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True

End Sub

'--------------New Function added here
Private Function GetFilesToIgnore() As Scripting.Dictionary

  Dim theList As Scripting.Dictionary
  theList.Add ThisWorkbook.Name, 1

  Dim usedCell As Range
  For Each usedCell In skipList.UsedRange
    theList.Add usedCell.Value, 1
  Next

  Set GetFilesToIgnore = theList

End Function
```

The code assumes that there is a contiguous list of cells in the `SkipList` worksheet that contain the names of the files to be ignored. It first adds *ThisWorkbook.Name* to the dictionary, then  adds the rest of the names from that list into the dictionary.

Now, instead of just skipping `ThisWorkbook.Name`, you skip if the name exists in the dictionary. This adds the benefit of automatically skipping `ThisWorkbook` even if its name is changed in addition to having an easily editable list of other files to ignore.

Note that a `Dictionary` is usually a `Key/Value` pair - You use it to quickly retrieve a `Value` by its `Key`. In this case, we really don't care about a `Value`, we're just using it because looking the `Key` up in a `Dictionary` is very fast. Therefore, I've used a hard-coded `1` as the value that's tied to all the `Key`s. It's a throw away number and could be changed to `Doesn't matter` or anything else that makes you happy.

Also, using `SkipList.UsedRange` is a quick-n-dirty solution. `.UsedRange` will return blank cells if you ever remove a name from the list, so it's probably not the best in the long run.