# Is there a simpler way of moving a lot of data

Tags: excel, vba

Basically i am making a program that will find all of the players from different teams and move them to their own workbook. There is 12 age groups and 4 divisions per age group (AE, A, AA and AAA). The code below works for one team (Minor Novice AE). I was wondering if there is a way for me to sort all of these without having to re write the same code 48 times. Thanks :)

```
Sub Team()

    Dim rw As Long, lastrow As Long, MySel As Range 'Grabs skus and moves to new sheet


    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For rw = 1000 To 2 Step -1
            If .Cells(rw, 2).Value Like "*Minor Novice*" And .Cells(rw, 3).Value Like ("AE") Then
                If MySel Is Nothing Then
                    Set MySel = .Cells(rw, 1).EntireRow

                        Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\CODE\Team Lists\11 Minor Novice AE.xlsx"

                        Else
                            Set MySel = Union(MySel, .Cells(rw, 1).EntireRow)

                        End If
                    End If
                Next rw
            End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("M Novice AE")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Not MySel Is Nothing Then
            MySel.Copy Destination:=.Cells(lastrow + 1, 1)
            'MySel.Delete
        End If
    End With

    Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("M Novice AE").Range("A1:AY300")
    Rng.Copy
    Dim s11 As Workbook
    Set s11 = Workbooks("11 Minor Novice AE")
    Dim last As Long
    Dim Rngnew As Range

With s11.Sheets("Sheet1")
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        last = .Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Else
        last = 1
    End If
End With
    Set Rngnew = s11.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & last)

    Rngnew.PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd suggest setting up a 2nd worksheet with the combinations that you need to process similar to the answer I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57383316/2344413). Instead of having a single column of filenames, you'd have a column of "categories" (`*Minor Novice*`), Codes (`AE` - not sure what that indicates, but it seems important), and FileNames (`11 Minor Novice AE.xlsx`). Use that to feed the routine you've already written.

Answer (score 0):

This will generically split a list onto separate sheets based on the contents of columns B and C - from there you can export each sheet as a separate workbook

```
   Sub SplitIntoSheets()
    dim r as range
    set r = range("a1")
    r.parent.usedrange.sort key1:=range("B1"),key2:=range("2c1"),hasheader:=true 
    'sort by age,division
    dim oldname as string
    Do  'start loop
    if r.offset(0,1)&r.offset(0,2)<>oldstring then
    'need new sheet
        oldstring = r.offset(0,1)&r.offset(0,2) 'store new string
        AddSheet oldstring, r.parent
    end if
    r.entirerow.copy sheets(oldstring).range( rows.count,1).end(xlup).offset(1,0) 'copy row
    set r = r.offset(1,0)
    loop until r = ""
    end sub

    Sub AddSheet(s as string,source as worksheet)
    thisworkbook.worksheets.add
    activesheet.name = s
    source.rows(1).copy range("a1")  'copy titlw row from source sheet to new sheet

    end sub
```

Not at computer, can't test this, there may be typos, it assumes a single sheet to begin with.

Comment: oldstring has a ByRef argument type mismatch which im not sure what that is

Comment: Try changing dim oldname to oldstring. Can't test it, not at pc

Comment: Yeah, what they said. Sorry, started off using oldname then wrote oldstring

Answer (score 0):

Create a new workbook for every unique value:

```
Sub Copy_To_Workbooks()
'Note: This macro use the function LastRow
    Dim My_Range As Range
    Dim FieldNum As Long
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim foldername As String
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim CCount As Long
    Dim WSNew As Worksheet
    Dim ErrNum As Long

    'Set filter range on ActiveSheet: A1 is the top left cell of your filter range
    'and the header of the first column, D is the last column in the filter range.
    'You can also add the sheet name to the code like this :
    'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D" & LastRow(Worksheets("Sheet1")))
    'No need that the sheet is active then when you run the macro when you use this.
    Set My_Range = Range("A1:D" & LastRow(ActiveSheet))
    My_Range.Parent.Select

    If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure = True Or _
       My_Range.Parent.ProtectContents = True Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, not working when the workbook or worksheet is protected", _
               vbOKOnly, "Copy to new workbook"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'This example filters on the first column in the range(change the field if needed)
    'In this case the range starts in A so Field:=1 is column A, 2 = column B, ......
    FieldNum = 1

    'Turn off AutoFilter
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    'Set the file extension/format
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        'You use Excel 97-2003
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        'You use Excel 2007-2013
        If ActiveWorkbook.FileFormat = 56 Then
            FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
        Else
            FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
        End If
    End If

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

    'Delete the sheet RDBLogSheet if it exists
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("RDBLogSheet").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Add worksheet to copy/Paste the unique list
    Set ws2 = Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
    ws2.Name = "RDBLogSheet"

    'Fill in the path\folder where you want the new folder with the files
    'you can use also this "C:\Users\Ron\test"
    MyPath = Application.DefaultFilePath

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'Create folder for the new files
    foldername = MyPath & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss") & "\"
    MkDir foldername

    With ws2
        'first we copy the Unique data from the filter field to ws2
        My_Range.Columns(FieldNum).AdvancedFilter _
                Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                CopyToRange:=.Range("A3"), Unique:=True

        'loop through the unique list in ws2 and filter/copy to a new sheet
        Lrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For Each cell In .Range("A4:A" & Lrow)

            'Filter the range
            My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum, Criteria1:="=" & _
             Replace(Replace(Replace(cell.Value, "~", "~~"), "*", "~*"), "?", "~?")

            'Check if there are no more then 8192 areas(limit of areas)
            CCount = 0
            On Error Resume Next
            CCount = My_Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) _
                     .Areas(1).Cells.Count
            On Error GoTo 0
            If CCount = 0 Then
                MsgBox "There are more than 8192 areas for the value : " & cell.Value _
                     & vbNewLine & "It is not possible to copy the visible data." _
                     & vbNewLine & "Tip: Sort your data before you use this macro.", _
                       vbOKOnly, "Split in worksheets"
            Else
                'Add new workbook with one sheet
                Set WSNew = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)

                'Copy/paste the visible data to the new workbook
                My_Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                With WSNew.Range("A1")
                    ' Paste:=8 will copy the columnwidth in Excel 2000 and higher
                    ' Remove this line if you use Excel 97
                    .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    .Select
                End With

                'Save the file in the new folder and close it
                On Error Resume Next
                WSNew.Parent.SaveAs foldername & _
                                    cell.Value & FileExtStr, FileFormatNum
                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    ErrNum = ErrNum + 1

                    WSNew.Parent.SaveAs foldername & _
                     "Error_" & Format(ErrNum, "0000") & FileExtStr, FileFormatNum

                    .Cells(cell.Row, "B").Formula = "=Hyperlink(""" & foldername & _
                      "Error_" & Format(ErrNum, "0000") & FileExtStr & """)"

                    .Cells(cell.Row, "A").Interior.Color = vbRed
                Else
                    .Cells(cell.Row, "B").Formula = _
                    "=Hyperlink(""" & foldername & cell.Value & FileExtStr & """)"
                End If

                WSNew.Parent.Close False
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If

            'Show all the data in the range
            My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=FieldNum

        Next cell
        .Cells(1, "A").Value = "Red cell: can't use the Unique name as file name"
        .Cells(1, "B").Value = "Created Files (Click on the link to open a file)"
        .Cells(3, "A").Value = "Unique Values"
        .Cells(3, "B").Value = "Full Path and File name"
        .Cells(3, "A").Font.Bold = True
        .Cells(3, "B").Font.Bold = True
        .Columns("A:B").AutoFit

    End With

    'Turn off AutoFilter
    My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False

    If ErrNum > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Rename every WorkSheet name that start with ""Error_"" manually" _
             & vbNewLine & "There are characters in the name that are not allowed" _
             & vbNewLine & "in a sheet name or the worksheet already exist."
    End If

    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
    My_Range.Parent.Select
    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
    ws2.Select
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With

End Sub


Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win006_3.htm